# Make android Bleutooth Always Discoverable

Tags: android, android-ndk

In Android 4.0 as used on the Nexus, there is an option to make bluetooth "always discoverable." Is it possible to do this programmatically? Also discussed [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=6348#makechanges).

Comment: Just like discussed there. But older versions wont support a value of 0, use some large value. But the user will always be able to switch it off anyways.

Comment: @ Péter Varga thanks.Yes user can be able to switch it off,but I don't want to set visible time limitations,In Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.1 there is option like visibility time out as 2 minutes,5 minutes,1 hous and "Never time out" . Last option in which I am interested is that "Never time out" ,So I want to do make Visibillity as "Never Time out" programatically,I don't want to mention timeout limit.

Comment: Thanks Peter Varga. . I here I am giving more detail on my question to make Bluetooth always visible for By default, the device will become discoverable for 120 seconds. You can define a different duration by adding the EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION Intent extra. The maximum duration an app can set is 3600 seconds, and a value of 0 means the device is always discoverable. Any value below 0 or above 3600 is automatically set to 120 secs). for more detail you can read heading as Enabling discoverability here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability